# Performance Difference in comparing integers and comparing strings

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone provide any concrete evidence of performance when comparing

```
int = int
```

and:

```
string = string
```

in `WHERE` clause in MS-SQL.

For example

```
select *
from Samples
where SamplesID = 5
```

and:

```
select *
from Samples
where Name = 'Shampoo'
```

Is there difference or is performance the same?

Comment: On a samples table I would expect the SamplesId to be the clustered index. The presence and or types of index have a massive effect. Is this a real or a theoretical question?

Comment: @SteveHenderson change your comment to be "expect the SamplesId to be the primary key", and I'd agree with you 100% :) Id columns usually designate keys, which may or may not be the clustered index.  Of course, that's just an assumption...

Comment: @StuartAinsworth No - I would also expect it to be the clustered index. With a simple lookup table (Id and Name, with some other stuff) I would expect the physical ordering of that lookup table to be by the Id (Primary key and clustered index).

Comment: I think that any test to answer this question should be between a lookup on an indexed int column and a lookup on an indexed varchar (or char) column.  In any situation where the performance matters, you would likely want to have an index on the column being used for the lookup. I expect that a lookup on an int column will almost always be faster, but how much faster will probably also depend greatly on the kind of data. If the string column contains a lot of rows that all start off with the same sequence of characters, then I think the index on that string column will be less effective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK interesting question always took it as read that integer was quicker and never actually tested it. I took 1M Random Surnames and types from a list of Contacts from my data into a scratch database with no indices or primary key just raw data. No measurement was made over the range of my data in either of the columns has not been standardised so reflects the reality of my database rather than a pure statistical set.

```
select top 100 * from tblScratch where contactsurname = '<TestSurname>' order by NEWID()
select top 100 * from tblScratch where contacttyperef = 1-22 order by NEWID()
```

The Newid is there to randomise the data list out each time. Quickly ran this for 20 surnames and 20 types. Queries were run surname than ref then surname. Searching for the reference number was almost 4x quicker and used about 1/2 so the books were right all those years ago.

String - 
`SELECT TOP 100 * FROM tblScratch WHERE contactsurname = 'hoare' ORDER BY NEWID()`

```
Duration 430ms
Reads 902
CPU 203
```

Integer - 
`SELECT TOP 100 * FROM tblScratch WHERE contacttyperef = 3 ORDER BY NEWID()`

```
Duration 136ms
Reads 902
CPU 79
```

Comment: so this means that comparing integers is less CPU intensive thus it resolves in better performance. 
is there any documentations from Microsoft on how comparison actually works?

Comment: It's not really a good test (sorry), and potentially misleading because ordering by NewID() introduces a totally unrealistic element - it generates and orders rows by a GUID. The optimiser will not necessarily do this after interpreting the WHERE statement. Can you take the TOP and the Order By NEWID() out and retest?

Answer (score 3):

Put both of your queries in the same query window. At the very top (before either of these queries) put: 
    SET STATISTICS IO ON

When you run the code run it with the option "Include Actual Execution Plan" (an icon on your toolbar which looks like three little boxes, about 7 icons to the right of the Execute button)

This will result in three tabs in your results: Results, Messages, Plan.
The Messages and the Plan will show you the IO cost and the full Execution cost.

The query with the bigger numbers has the highest cost!
This method will allow you to prove to yourself which query has the lowest cost (highest performance)

Comment: BTW, the reason I say to test it, rather than providing a textbook answer is that the optimiser runs a probability-based plan, and depending on size and indexes (as Stuart Ainsworth points out) is that sometimes it is faster to do a full table scan (especially with a SELECT *) than to perform an index lookup before getting the data, so the optimiser would ignore the index. 
Take textbook advice as a good starting point, but you really have to test it, and retest as table sizes and structures change

Answer (score 3):

As Steve pointed out in the comments, the presence and constitution of indexes will greatly impact your results; however, since SQL Server works with pages to lookup data, and narrower column types can store more data per page, using a narrow type can perform better than a wider type where there are more values to consider.

So, if you have a small table (few rows), it probably doesn't matter; big table?  Put an index on the int column and it will probably out-perform an indexed varchar column.

Of course, what constitutes large or small tables depends on your hardware.

Comment: This is also only true if he has long varchar fields.  since an `int` is 8 bytes, he needs to average over 6 characters per row of varchcar for `int` to be smaller

Comment: Specifics often ruin a good rule-of-thumb, but you can't answer every question with "it depends".  Tinyints (an integer value but not an int) are 1 byte, which is less than any varchar column (and equivalent to a char(1)).  The rule still applies; the narrower the type, the better potential for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing integers should be faster, at the very low level it will end up with 1 `cmp` instruction. Comparing string involves more instructions, and as a result, worse performance.
I assume you either have or don't have indexes on both fields, indexes are equally selective, number of records also the same

Comment: i understand that it should be faster but i'm trying to figure out if there is concrete way to prove that it is?
does this also means that different OS system or even hardware might approach differently when comparing strings versus comparing integers

Comment: I think the only 100% undeniable way to prove or refute it is to look into SQLServer source code that handles string and number comparision. Personally, I don't see how comparing non-empty strings (which is comparing of 2 arrays of numbers) can be faster then comparing just 2 numbers.