# Storing facebook id field in postgres database

Tags: facebook, postgresql, facebook-graph-api

I use FB APIs to get all the posts for a message.

While reviewing the return data, I noticed it in the following format.

```
88887444189_99993647936419190
```

Is there any standard data field type within POSTGRES that I can use by default?

It looks kind of UUID format but not sure.

Comment: `text`. You could change the underscore to a period and jam it into a `numeric`, but that'd be horrible. Unless FB's API docs specify its structure and meaning, treat it as an arbitrary identifier and store it as `text`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `text`.

You could change the underscore to a period and jam it into a `numeric`, but that'd be horrible.

Unless FB's API docs specify its structure and meaning, treat it as an arbitrary identifier and store it as `text`. Even if it looked like something recognisable, say a UUID, you should still use `text` unless it's *documented* to be a `UUID` or whatever. Otherwise your code could break later when it changes without warning because you relied on undocumented behaviour in the API.

Comment: Im planning to remove the underscore and jam it into a numeric as I will be using it as a key...Since its numeric, the processing also will be faster..Any reason why this approach is not good?

Comment: @user1050619 No! What makes you think it would be faster? Numbers aren't always faster. `NUMERIC` is a variable length type just like `text` and there is no advantage for equality comparison. Don't just do something because it seems like it might be faster. Test. What you should do is define the `text` column as `COLLATE "C"` to skip locale processing. That is all. Uff. I made the comment about numeric offhand because I thought it was too awful for anyone to take seriously. The only other OK data type would be `bytea`. Oh and varchar but that performs exactly the same as text in Pg.

Comment: Thanks..Here is an SO article that mentioned integer/numeric comparison is faster..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904179/why-is-integer-comparsion-faster-then-string-comparion

Comment: There is one more - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8124448/performance-difference-in-comparing-integers-and-comparing-strings..The reason I'm hesitant is because of the number of bytes in the id field.

Comment: @user1050619 Um, that's `integer` not `numeric`. Those oranges are lookin' awfully green and crunchy to me. These values are too big for an integer, otherwise it might be a good idea. `NUMERIC` is arbitrary-precision decimal floating point stored as a binary-coded decimal string. You can't use an integer for this (the value won't fit and it isn't an integer anyway) and the types it *will* fit in are all roughly equivalent in performance.

Comment: There are various things you could do to jam it into other representations, like uuid, but they'd be (a) completely wrong conceptually, (b) horrible to work with, and (c) little if any performance improvement. Also, as far as I can see FB doesn't document the identifier structure, so your app would break if it changed. Use `text`. If you absolutely insist on doing wacky representation gymnastics it looks like the value would fit in a pair of `BIGINT` fields, but really, you're just buying yourself later pain by doing that.